Why would a 20 year old MOSFET fail?
I have an old MOSFET power amplifier which dates from (I think) 1997 or so. It was made by a well known British manufacturer. I bought it used about a decade ago, and it has worked faultlessly.
A few weeks back it didn't power om, the cause turned out to be the fuse, in turn caused by an output power MOSFET, IRF540, that was dead short.
No big problem, replace, carry on, right? But why would a MOSFET which has been stable for years, and which was not subjected to any heavy duty use or otherwise, suddenly do this?
Maybe other components drifted out of spec? Perhaps spikes coming through the mains?
As far as I know there is no real "aging" mechanism in transistors, so long as they are used within their normal limits, am I correct?

What device was connected to the output of the power amp? Maybe the fault is further down the line and the transistor was the first thing to fail in that line. Also look for polarised capacitors on the PCB, they are often the culprit. If they have corosion on them or are bend, they are most likely dead.

@HansmitmFlammenwerfer - nothing different to what has been connected for the last few years - a pair of normal 8R speakers. I will check the wiring though. Electrolytics motsly only dry out when they run hot, in my experience, anyway I don't see how they would cause a power MOSFET failure.

One aging mechanism is heat-cold cycle. In a home, the temperature swing is low but each one will stress it. Another thing lurking in the background is cosmic radiation. Many MOSFETs will survive such an event but keep a sufficient number of devices energized for long enough time, one will just out of the blue fail to short from it.

Is this a class-D amplifier or a linear (class-AB) one?

@JonathanS. AB for sure. It's an ARCAM Alpha 6.

Transistors have many aging mechanisms. They are mostly driven by stresses (high temperature, high current, high voltage, radiation, ...) although corrosion and chemical contamination can play a role, too.

GENTLEMEN (also any ladies if involved). The technical conversation in answers and comments is so far excellent and informative. There has been a certain amount of somewhat spirited disagreement - which is fine. All please endeavour to keep things at no more spirited than this. This is the sort of discussion that can and has previously overflowed into unacceptable behaviour and undesired consequences. Again - what I see so far is fine and useful. I'm just hoping to head off at the pass what sometimes happens.

One personal 'challenge' was put more marginally than I'd have thought ideal, but as there was no reaction to it it caused no escalation. || Input to date is excellent. Hopefully we can have this level of discussion in future without problems.

Given the vintage of the amp, I'll assume that it's Class-AB (linear), not Class-D (switching).
Linear MOSFET power amplifiers often aren't designed particularly well. Many of them suffer from parasitic oscillations caused by the large gate-source capacitance of the output power MOSFETs, which are quite difficult to dampen and can get worse over time as surrounding components (such as compensation capacitors) age. This is a common theme in MOSFET amp repairs which typically causes blown-up / shorted power FETs. If you replace the FETs without fixing the underlying design issue of the amp, they'll most likely die again.
Another thing that's often done wrong is the selection of suitable MOSFETs. Your amp gets this wrong as well - the IRF540 is not rated for linear operation, as evidenced by its datasheet lacking a DC curve in its SOA plot. It's a HEXFET, which means that it's constructed out of hundreds or even thousands of tiny hexagonal MOSFET cells connected in parallel on its die. When driven into its linear operating region, these cells will not conduct current equally, causing hotspots to develop. This causes the MOSFETs to fail rapidly.
So in short, it's not actually surprising that the IRF540 failed here. It's more surprising that it even worked for a while in the first place.
Proper MOSFET-based amplifiers typically use planar MOSFETs, which don't suffer from the same hotspot problems as HEXFETs when driven into the linear region. IXYS (now Littelfuse) has a series of such FETs if I remember correctly.
International Rectifier has an application note detailing how HEXFETs fail when operated in linear mode, which also includes a thermal image of a hotspot developing on a FET die. They also note that more modern devices are more likely to fail in this way, which likely also includes later revisions of classic part numbers if there has been a die re-spin to reduce manufacturing cost.

Semiconductors have a large temperature range with negative temperature coefficient for resistance, so even uniform transistors have a spontaneously developing hotspot problem when used in linear operation near their thermal limits ("secondary breakdown").  Of course the gate voltage variation of paralleled FETs is an additional big starting ramp for this kind of trouble.

How could one tell that it isn't suitable for linear operation from the datasheet? Which parameters or graphs should one look for?

@Lundin the first page of the data sheet is the initial giveaway when it talks about fast switching (rather than linear operation). Figure 3 is also a bit of a giveaway in that it shows where thermal runaway occurs (below a VGS of around 5.2 volts). Just think what happens to the drain current when biased at a VGS of 4 volts and the MOSFET starts to warm up <-- the drain current rises and the MOSFET gets warmer <-- what stops this process? If you look at "linear" MOSFETs the effect of warming tends to be less pronounced.

interesting answer - thank you. Well it has worked really well for 20 years or so, so I am not worried too much about replacing all the output devices, setting the bias, and enjoying it for 20 or so more. I will take a good look with the scope though for any stability stuff, that seems like a good idea. Run some square waves into a load and so on. Run it for a few hours into a resistive load as well.

It's a myth that (common) MOSFETs aren't rated for linear use: the rating is conferred by the SOA and requires no further discussion; for these parts in particular, the original IR databooks discuss such operation, as you would any other transistor at the time ('80s).

@Andyaka The process stops because amplifiers do not apply a fixed Vgs(bias). Please stop perpetuating this myth -- you've repeated this factoid across about half a dozen posts here.

@TimWilliams I'm sorry but you are completely wrong and I have witnessed it and got a well-known supplier to confirm that this was happening. Then there's the whole "why do IXYS make linear MOSFET thing" <-- are you saying it's a scare-marketing strategy to make more sales? Then there is the spirito effect and NASA reporting this problem and, a lot of the top suppliers also reporting the problem. Are you denying it all?

I am completely wrong that amplifiers do not apply fixed Vgs(bias)? No amplifier in the history of amplifiers has ever used temperature compensation? Come on Andy, I know you know analog circuitry better than this. Don't deflect with "but this product" "but that thing", stick to the claim. (Though out of scope here, I've provided separate critiques of the other two claims as well.)

@TimWilliams The problem isn't the externally-applied Vgs but instead that the same Vgs is applied to all of the paralleled internal MOSFET cells of the HEXFET. If one of those cells gets hotter than the others (in linear mode), its threshold voltage drops and the current through it increases relative to the other cells even if the total device current remains the same. At some point, all current concentrates on one or a few cells, which then melt. In a hard switching (resistive) mode, the tempco is opposite and the current through the hottest cell decreases instead, which is fine.

It failed because it was exhausted from a lifetime of work and wanted to die.

@JonathanS. Now we're making progress; but this omits a key fact: there is thermal resistance between cells of a MOSFET. The correct analysis is not "there's instability ergo it's toast", it's "how far until instability causes runaway failure?" -- a more subtle point, and only one reference I've seen (correctly) gives up at this point, noting that manufacturers do not publish thermal diffusivity characteristics and therefore we have only one fallback: the SOA as plotted.

Which, I've heard paranoia that the SOA might sometimes be invalid ("calculated") -- maliciously or otherwise. But not a single person claiming such has provided proof of this; I can only assume they think so from hearsay. If it doesn't have test results it might as well not exist.

@TimWilliams Runaway isn't needed for linear mode to cause damage to a HEXFET. The hotspots are always present when such a FET is used in linear mode, making the die locally hotter than the junction-to-case thermal resistance specifies. This means that you can no longer rely on the latter to design your heatsinking. If the design has a marginal heatsink to begin with, the hotspots will push parts of the FET die beyond Tjmax, making it age rapidly even if it doesn't immediately die. The problem is that you can't know just how hot it gets in the package, so it's always a gamble.

@JonathanS. Right, if there's hotspotting, the peak temp rises for given Pd. So we reduce Pd to maintain Tjmax. There's an exponent to it, so Pd must reduce along a relatively steep curve (but not simply to zero anywhere in such a region, that would be preposterous). Which perfectly describes 2nd breakdown, and SOA as plotted (for affected devices). And why small devices don't exhibit 2nd breakdown (die is too small, Pd too low, to activate 2nd breakdown).

Great Application Note. Thompson is quite the joker: "Figure II-3: Visual Image of the IRF1405Z failure. This type of visual pattern is more attractive when observed on the surface of the moon, instead of on the surface of parts that are trying to land there"

Yeah, I heard it before "These MOSFETs are not rated for linear use!"
There are millions of amps using oldskool FETs like IRFP240/9240 in linear mode.
More modern FETs are a different story, they will blow up if used in linear mode. But while these old FETs are not "officially" rated for linear mode, everyone uses them, everyone knows they will work absolutely fine and are extremely rugged.
But... there's of course a limit to how bad the design can be...
Let's look at the amp first.

What the hell? Where's the heat sink? It's a class AB amp, so there should be a heat sink, right? Are they... these ridiculously tiny thumb-sized things on the back of the amp?
It's a 2x50W amp so you'd expect at least 4x bigger heat sink, in a place where there's actually airflow. Compare with this random amp:

I prefer heat sinks on the sides though. They still work when the cat sits on the enclosure.
Even if the heat sinking was adequate, one pair of TO-220 devices is not enough for a 50W amp. First, TO220 has little thermal mass, so it heats up too quickly. Second, the contact area at the back is tiny, so the thermal interface between device and heat sink is always a problem.
Class AB amps have reasonably low average dissipation but peaks can be high, and power peaks tend to occur at bass frequency, which means they last long enough to heat a TO-220 to dangerous levels.
TO-247 packages offer a good amount of thermal mass, because the chip is mounted on a big chunk of copper, which helps immensely to soak up dissipation peaks. This keeps the peak junction temperature down, so while TO247 is a bit more expensive, they will get away with a smaller cheaper heatsink.
One big weak point of TO220 is the thermal interface between the device and the heat sink. The more contact area with the heat sink, the lower thermal resistance, and TO-247 wins by a wide margin simply because it's huge. These will take a lot of abuse. TO-220, not so much.
So if you use TO220 you need several in parallel. But paralleling devices with negative threshold voltage temperature coefficient is always a headache. That's why I expected to see the usual P/N pair of TO-247 IRFP240-9240 devices per channel.
Well, in this amp's case, it doesn't matter, because there's no heat sink.
A quick look at the service manual reveals a complete absence of any protection circuit of any kind: output short, overcurrent, overtemperature, etc.
Likely cause of death is exceeding max Tj repeatedly and at length. In fact the MOSFETs did pretty well if they survived that kind of abuse for that long, I'm impressed!...
So basically, it failed because the design is garbage.

It's a myth that (common) MOSFETs aren't rated for linear use: the rating is conferred by the SOA and requires no further discussion; for these parts in particular, the original IR databooks discuss such operation, as you would any other transistor at the time ('80s).

Yes they work just fine.

"More modern FETs are a different story, they will blow up if used in linear mode." - Is this a thing of experience with specific part numbere or package types or construction types? Can one anticipate this based on datasheet? Personally I've never had issues in linear mode with any MOSFET, but probably haven't been pushing the dissipation envelope.

absence of any protection what about FS1; FS201/FS202?

@tobalt Yes: follow the SOA curves. Whether a device is reliable (survives N temp cycles, from X to Y temp, and at whatever rate) is an excellent question, but basic function is guaranteed by SOA (to whatever confidence the manufacturer provides with such data).  Seems to me, most trench MOS hit 2nd breakdown limit in the 10-50V range; SJ (>200V) vary, with some having full SOA and some not.

@tobalt looking at the SOA curve on this link, if you see just the lines 1,2,3,5 then it's a hint the FET may be good for linear mode. If you see line 3 bending down into line 4 (cyan) that's second breakdown / Spirito instability, and the FET is a bad choice for linear mode.

@greybeard When the FET is shorted, the full DC supply voltage gets on the output. The fuse is there to protect the loudspeaker from burning out or starting a fire. But transistors will fry before the fuses open, as usual.

thanks bob and @TimWilliams. The second breakdown region as an indicator is something I will try to remember whenever I need to go close to the SOA boundary in linear mode .

The thermal engineering on that amplifier is an oxymoron. There is none. WOW.

All electronic components are subject to aging, even MOSFETs. This is directly related to temperature, so a FET with an inadequate heatsink, package, thermal interface, or all three will be vulnerable to failure.
A 1997 vintage amp is likely Class AB. It's still a popular approach to making high power (e.g., 200W) amplifiers as a hobbyist thing owing to its simplicity, and because FETs are fairly easy to connect in parallel. Nowadays you can roll your own Class D if that floats your boat.
That said, Tripath introduced their Class D amplifier in 1996 (fun fact: in that timeframe I met Tripathi and saw his demo of a 2x20W amp - impressive.)
What happened to your amp though? High-power MOSFETs are vulnerable to Spirito Effect, which shows up with high transconductance FETS (e.g., trench FETs) as formation of localized unstable hot spots due to uneven cell matching. It's kind of like bipolar transistor mismatch in output stages, but on a more micro scale.
A bit more here: Mosfet thermal problems in linear applications
The takeaway: FETs operated in linear mode are even more vulnerable to Spirito effect, so require derating of their Safe Operating Area (SoA).
As for your amp, it was a good run while it lasted. If you can, maybe replace the FETs with physically bigger ones, and work up an improved heat sinking system.
Feeling adventurous? Could be an opportunity to explore SiC, GaN or GaN-on-SiC.

"FETs are fairly easy to connect in parallel." - This directly contradicts what you mention about HEXFETs. The easy-to-parallel logic only really applies to switching applications such as Class D, I guess.

Somebody apparently forgot to tell these folks: https://www.elcircuit.com/2017/09/High-power-amplifier-circuit-mosfet.html

The operating mode of a power MOSFET amp is PWM, with the MOSFET alternating between blocking large voltage and admitting large current.  That causes very little heat dissipation.
The question is what happens during power-up and power-down.  When the gate voltage range gets smaller, the MOSFET may no longer open completely, meaning that its losses get much larger.
Depending on how power-up and power-down of the whole amp (including preamp) are sequenced and whether this sequence is messed up when the power switch bounces or otherwise the power sequence is interrupted, there may be moments of extra strain, like when the amp tries to route a preamp pop to the speakers during supply voltage low levels, further depleting the power supply capacitors.  If the power supply capacitors hold more energy than the MOSFETs can safely dissipate, the sequence matters, and brown-outs might lead to multiple restarts of the sequence while the MOSFET junction has not yet dissipated the heat from the first shutdown.

Not all MOSFET-based amplifiers are class-D. Linear designs are quite common as well, although they tend to have problems with their power FETs failing...

PCM? As in Class D? If the PA is from 1997, it's most likely a Class AB.

@JonathanS. I'd have thought that the vast exemplar gate voltage variation would not bode well for linear designs.  At least you'd have quite some difficulty providing circuit diagrams with dependable idling voltages...  Also the specs for IRF540 state "IRF540 is a third generation power MOSFET with low on-resistance, fast switching and rugged design. It has a TO-220AB package, a 100 V drain-source breakdown voltage and a 28 A pulsed drain current rating." which sounds intended for D-class operation.

@user107063 Indeed, the IRF540 is not a linear FET. It's unfortunately very common to see it in linear designs from the late 1990s / early 2000s, and it's also very common for it to fail when used in those designs.

All MOSFETs can be used in the linear region, but some are more suitable for it than others. Manufacturers will probably pick the cheapest option which passes their tests.

it's not class D. AB for certain, you can see on the schematic, which is easy enough to find online. This amp dates from 1997.

@JonathanS. Can you provide a citation from contemporary IR databooks indicating they're not rated for linear use? (I think you will find quite the opposite, actually.) I read the claim as "hey guys check these MOSFETs out, they're not slow BJTs, you can actually switch fast with efficiency now!". That's a much more relevant claim for the era.

PCM? I think you mean PWM or PDM. In PCM, each bit gets the same amount of time, whether it's the most significant bit or least significant bit.
